# Cannot access SharedWithMe Folders via microsoft graph api

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to download the items of a shared folder following the v1.0 [reference guide](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_sharedwithme). I am able to retrieve the basic details by using the /v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe request.

sharedWithMe Response

[image]

However when I try and request the contents of the folder using the `'/drives/remoteItem.driveId/items/id'` request I get a 'itemNotFound' error code.

> /drives/b!SuVijei8UUiLXWR4XeJPFe-SS3gbCDVJuXZLcatX7Ikm3BPqZMVJTLOW4rsDD7B2/items/01GB75254SYRXS4C7C25HLIWFMXFY7HWB3

```
"error": {
"code": "itemNotFound",
"message": "The resource could not be found.",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "2a0591bd-6fdf-4bf8-a5f3-baca24fd1930",
  "date": "2016-08-29T14:03:25"
}
```

Any ideas what is going on?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I was able to retrieve SharedWithMe folders data by using the '/drives/remoteitem.parentReference.driveId/items/remoteItem.id/children'
It seems also very important to use a scope of Files.Read.All (which seems to be currently undocumented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are almost there. All you need is the /content segment.

Expected: `/drives/remoteItem.parentReference.driveId/items/id/content`

Your actual: `/drives/remoteItem.parentReference.driveId/items/id`

You'll get redirected to the resource for download. I think the documentation should be updated

And just to make sure, the base url is a bit different:

To get the shared item content: `/v1.0/drives/drive-id/items/item-id/content`

To get the list of shared items: `/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe`

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. I am still getting the same 'itemNotFound' error code. I noticed comparing my 'sharedWithMe' response to the docs response that my id and remoteId are identical, while they are not identical in the docs. Also I am lacking a parentReference Id attribute. Perhaps this is part of my problem?

Comment: @RyanZ I think that it's expected that id and remoteId are identical. I'm not sure what you mean by lacking a parentReference Id attribute. I see that your sharedWithMe response contains it. Can you confirm that you are using the correct base URL? No /me/ or /users/user/ segments in it.

Comment: Okay I just wanted to make sure since the docs have different ids. I was referencing that my parentReference does not have an Id, it does however have the driveId. I thought perhaps this could be a clue that something is wrong/missing.
I can confirm I am using the correct base. This is what my request looks like: 'graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!SuVijei8UUiLXWR4XeJPFe-SS3gbCDVJuXZLcatX7Ikm3BPqZMVJTLOW4rsDD7B2/items/01GB75254SYRXS4C7C25HLIWFMXFY7HWB3/content'
I am using the Files.ReadWrite scope. 
Curious if this is reproducible for anyone else.

Comment: Oddly enough it works now if i replace 'content' with 'children' since it is a type of folder. I could have sworn this was not working yesterday :)

Comment: @MichaelMainer the documented call to retrieve the DriveItem fails (I believe it previously worked). Using the drive-id and itemId found in the shared folder's RemoteItem, attempting to retrieve the detailed properties of that folder (not the children) always returns a 404. For example, from above: /v1.0/drives/b!SuVijei8UUiLXWR4XeJPFe-SS3gbCDVJuXZLcatX7Ikm3BPqZMVJTLOW4rsDD7B2/items/01GB75254SYRXS4C7C25HLIWFMXFY7HWB3 should return a single DriveItem - it does not. Seems like a bug.